# What is the "Rails Way" to create the related row at the time the other row is created in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two tables: Lessons and Pages

- lessons "has_many" pages
- pages "belongs_to" lessons

When a new lesson is created I want the first page to be created at the same time.
The first page will have:

- the lesson_id column equal to the newly created lessons id
- the title column equal to the newly created lessons title

Comment: use an `after_create` filter in your `Lesson` model

Comment: Can you give an example of after_create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages
  before_create :create_first_page

  def create_first_page
    if pages.empty?
      pages.build(:title => title)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why do you use before_create instead of after_create?

Comment: It's not a big deal in this case; `after_create` would do about as well. I like having the opportunity abort early, to modify attributes of the lesson as well (e.g. a counter cache) in here, etc., but in your use case it's pretty similar.

Do note that if you use `after_create` you will want to call `pages.create` instead of `pages.build`: the former will save the new page, but the latter will not (since it will be saved when ActiveRecord saves the lesson).